# TortoiseSVN commit specific filetypes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to commit only specific filetypes. For example all the .php files in a project.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window that pops up when you're committing allowing you to select which files to commit actually has a column for Extension. You may have to make the window slightly larger to do that. Once you see it you can sort by extension and make your selection.

Comment: Yes I did that but I have to manually check about 2300 files (it is a huge project take over)

Comment: You can click the top one, scroll down, press shift and click the bottom one.

Comment: Wow never thought to do that!! thnx!